# Making a function that executes on firebase deploy

Tags: function, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I need to make a function that runs right after deployment without any actions like update/create.

The function needs to run a indefinite amouth of times (just an updater that clears information from database every 2 hours)

The thing i'm struggling with is making the function run right after deployment.

I'm not(can't) using firebase in built .schedule or http.

I'm not limited to firebase it just needs to a function that runs on deployment.

Is their a way to do it? If so how?

Comment: You could use CI/CD pipelines like http://gitlab.com to do this upon merge into the master branch. You can also setup schedules to run every 2 hours.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to do this.  If you want a Cloud Function to execute, you will have to trigger it somehow.

If you just want some code to run once, Cloud Functions is not really the right product to use.  Instead, consider just writing a script and running it whenever it needs to run.

Comment: The second paragraph seems like presumptuous generalization. In our case, the express server has a list of all its payment hooks and updating the payment hooks on deployment (currently it requires a specific endpoint to be called) would allow for the endpoints to stay in sync. A scripts runs the risk of having both being off sync.

Comment: @Ced What you're describing doesn't sound like a "just once" use case. If you intend to run something multiple times, then yes, maybe a different solution is in order for you.

Comment: It's just once after deployment. Adding a post deployment script would do too, but this does not have "transaction" support (we would like both to succeed or none). That's why something built it might be interesting, although this is a very minor issue, to me at least, just a would have been nice to have.